# Need to display different json files on the basis of nation selected in the drop down menu

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

[This is HTML output of page designed using ajax and javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTfLD.png)

As of now I can search and let people know about the rank of the person entered name in the search box.

I need to display my json according to the nation selected by the user.
I have included an external json file. 
Your help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

This is my json file.

```
{
   "person": [
       {
           "rank": "1",
           "name": "Kent1",
           "runScored": "30",
           "nation": "dhaka"
       },
       {
           "rank": "2",
           "name": "Kent2",
           "runScored": "44",
           "nation": "johannesberg"
       },
       {
           "rank": "3",
           "name": "Kent3",
           "runScored": "20",
           "nation": "lahore"
       },
       {
           "rank": "4",
           "name": "Kent4",
           "runScored": "18",
           "nation": "india"
       },
       {
           "rank": "5",
           "name": "Kent5",
           "runScored": "16",
           "nation": "australia"
       },
       {
           "rank": "6",
           "name": "Kent6",
           "runScored": "14",
           "nation": "johannesberg"
       },
       {
           "rank": "7",
           "name": "Kent7",
           "runScored": "12",
           "nation": "australia"
       },
       {
           "rank": "8",
           "name": "Kent8",
           "runScored": "11",
           "nation": "india"
       },
       {
           "rank": "9",
           "name": "Kent9",
           "runScored": "10",
           "nation": "lahore"
       },
       {
           "rank": "10",
           "name": "Kent10",
           "runScored": "6",
           "nation": "dhaka"
       },
       {
           "rank": "11",
           "name": "Kent11",
           "runScored": "44",
           "nation": "colombo"
       },
       {
           "rank": "12",
           "name": "Kent12",
           "runScored": "20",
           "nation": "colombo"
       },
       {
           "rank": "13",
           "name": "Kent13",
           "runScored": "18",
           "nation": "india"
       },
       {
           "rank": "14",
           "name": "Kent14",
           "runScored": "16",
           "nation": "johannesberg"
       },
       {
           "rank": "15",
           "name": "Kent15",
           "runScored": "14",
           "nation": "colombo"
       },
       {
           "rank": "16",
           "name": "Kent16",
           "runScored": "44",
           "nation": "india"
       },
       {
           "rank": "17",
           "name": "Kent17",
           "runScored": "20",
           "nation": "dhaka"
       },
       {
           "rank": "18",
           "name": "Kent18",
           "runScored": "18",
           "nation": "lahore"
       },
       {
           "rank": "19",
           "name": "Kent19",
           "runScored": "16",
           "nation": "australia"
       },
       {
           "rank": "20",
           "name": "Kent20",
           "runScored": "14",
           "nation": "australia"
       }
   ]
}
```

THIS IS MY CODE.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

 function sortFunction() {
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.year - b.year});
    displayCars();
}


 let dropdown = $('#locality-dropdown');
 dropdown.empty();

// dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose your Nation</option>');
// dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);


 const url = 'http://api.myjson.com/bins/zpaxo';

// Populate dropdown with list of provinces
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function (key, entry) { 
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.abbreviation).text(entry.name));
  })
});

/*$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#isSelect").click(function () {

    alert($('#country').val());

    });

    $("#selectChina").click(function () {

    $("#country").val("China");

    });

    $("#selectUS").click(function () {

    $("#country").val("United State");

    });

   $("#selectMalaysia").click(function () {

    $("#country").val("Malaysia");

    });

    $("#disableUS").click(function () {

    $("#country option[value='United State']").attr("disabled", true);

    });

    $("#enableUS").click(function () {

    $("#country option[value='United State']").attr("disabled", false);

    });

  });*/
    //$(function() {
    //var people = [];
       //$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.ajax({
       url: "p.json",
       dataType: 'json',
       type: 'get',
       cache: false,
       success: function(data){
            $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" +  "<td>" + f.runScored + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nation + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
           return i<9;
           });          
        }
        });

   //})

//});

function onclickbutton(){
           document.getElementById("button");  
           //var searchField = "name";
           //$.getJSON('p.json', function(data) {

           $.ajax({
            url: "p.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
            $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          //people.sort((a, b) => b.querySelector('.runScored').textContent - a.querySelector('.runScored').textContent);
          //var searchVal = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
          if (f.name == document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value) {
           var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.runScored + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nation + "</td>" + "</tr>"
              $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
              } 
           });          
        }
        });
            //});

    }


</script>

<style>

  h1 {

    font-size: 30px;
    color: #e1e1e1;
    padding-top: 12px;

  }

body {  
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
}

table {
    width: 50%;
    border-spacing: 0 0;
    background: #213B4C;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1E3344;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#userdata tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#userdata tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #fff;
}
table#userdata th {
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
    }

h4 {
color: black;
}    
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="leaderboard">
<h1 align="center">
    LEADERBOARD
</h1>

<div class="main" align=center>
<select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality">
<option selected="true" disabled>Choose your Nation</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
            <option value="Johannesberg">Johannesberg</option>
            <option value="Colombo">Colombo</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Dhaka">Dhaka</option>
</select><br>
<!--<input type='button' value='Display Selected' id='isSelect'>
<input type='button' value='Select China' id='selectChina'>
<input type='button' value='Select US' id='selectUS'>
<input type='button' value='Select Malaysia' id='selectMalaysia'>
<input type='button' value='Disable US' id='disableUS'>
<input type='button' value='Enable US' id='enableUS'>-->

<h4>Enter your name to get your Rank Here</h4>

<form name="myForm" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="onclickbutton()" method="get">
Name:  <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
  <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Runs Scored</th>
            <th>Nation</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>


</div>
<!--<input id="userinput" type="text" name="searchName"> 
<button id="button" onclick="onclickbutton()">Search</button>-->
<!--</div>
</div>
-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    function sortFunction() {
      cars.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.year - b.year
      });
      displayCars();
    }


    let dropdown = $('#locality-dropdown');
    dropdown.empty();

    // dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose your Nation</option>');
    // dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);


    const url = 'http://api.myjson.com/bins/zpaxo';

    // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.abbreviation).text(entry.name));
      })
    });

    /*$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#isSelect").click(function () {

        alert($('#country').val());

        });

        $("#selectChina").click(function () {

        $("#country").val("China");

        });

        $("#selectUS").click(function () {

        $("#country").val("United State");

        });

       $("#selectMalaysia").click(function () {

        $("#country").val("Malaysia");

        });

        $("#disableUS").click(function () {

        $("#country option[value='United State']").attr("disabled", true);

        });

        $("#enableUS").click(function () {

        $("#country option[value='United State']").attr("disabled", false);

        });

      });*/
    //$(function() {
    //var people = [];
    //$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.runScored + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nation + "</td>" + "</tr>"
          $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
          return i < 9;
        });
      }
    });

    //})

    //});

    function onclickbutton() {
      document.getElementById("button");
      //var searchField = "name";
      //$.getJSON('p.json', function(data) {

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
            //people.sort((a, b) => b.querySelector('.runScored').textContent - a.querySelector('.runScored').textContent);
            //var searchVal = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
            if (f.name == document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value) {
              var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.runScored + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nation + "</td>" + "</tr>"
              $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            }
          });
        }
      });
      //});

    }

    function handleSelectChange(event) {
      const selectElement = event.target;
      const nation = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#userdata tbody").html('');
          $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
            if (f.nation !== nation) return;
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.runScored + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.nation + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            return i < 9;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #e1e1e1;
      padding-top: 12px;
    }

    body {
      background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
    }

    table {
      width: 50%;
      border-spacing: 0 0;
      background: #213B4C;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1E3344;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    table#userdata tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    table#userdata tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    table#userdata th {
      background-color: grey;
      color: black;
    }

    h4 {
      color: black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="leaderboard">
    <h1 align="center">
    LEADERBOARD
</h1>

    <div class="main" align=center>
      <select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality" onchange="handleSelectChange(event)">
        <option selected="true" disabled>Choose your Nation</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="lahore">Lahore</option>
        <option value="johannesberg">Johannesberg</option>
        <option value="colombo">Colombo</option>
        <option value="australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="dhaka">Dhaka</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <!--<input type='button' value='Display Selected' id='isSelect'>
<input type='button' value='Select China' id='selectChina'>
<input type='button' value='Select US' id='selectUS'>
<input type='button' value='Select Malaysia' id='selectMalaysia'>
<input type='button' value='Disable US' id='disableUS'>
<input type='button' value='Enable US' id='enableUS'>-->

      <h4>Enter your name to get your Rank Here</h4>

      <form name="myForm" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="onclickbutton()" method="get">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <br>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="profile">
          <table id="userdata" border="2">
            <thead>
              <th>Rank</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Runs Scored</th>
              <th>Nation</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
          </table>


        </div>
        <!--<input id="userinput" type="text" name="searchName">
<button id="button" onclick="onclickbutton()">Search</button>-->
        <!--</div>
</div>
-->
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Doing minimal changes to your code, added new method, added onchange listener to select and lowercased the option values, for matching

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to segregate from the json with different nations @villu164

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you let me know how to filter the json data in jquery so that I can display it according to the different nations.